# sectioning 2d array from input file java

Tags: java, arrays, custom-sections

Can someone help me out? A total of 3 sections, section 1 is the first index, the sub sequential sections are the sum total of every 5 index's there after.  Do not know why I keep getting an exception error.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double min, max, sum = 0, avg = 0;// DecimalFormat class is used to format the output
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".0");// DecimalFormat class is used to format the output
    DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat(".00");
    int rows = 0, cols = 0;
    String names[] = null;
    double scores[][] = null;
    double scoressec[][] = null;

    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try { //Opening the input file
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Input.txt"));//Reading the no of rows and columns
        rows = sc.nextInt();//check
        cols = sc.nextInt();
        names = new String[rows];
        scores = new double[rows][cols - 1];
        scoressec = new double[rows][0];
        /* Getting the data from the input file
         * and populate those values into array
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            names[i] = sc.next();
            for (int j = 0; j < cols - 1; j++) {
                scores[i][j] = sc.nextDouble();

                if (j == 0) {
                    scoressec[i][1] = scores[i][1];
                } else if (j == 5) {
                    scoressec[i][2] += scores[i][j] - scores[i][1];
                } else {
                    scoressec[i][3] += scores[i][j] - scoressec[i][2];
                }
            }


        } //closing the input file`
```

Comment: You defined `scoressec = new double[rows][0];` (which makes no sense by the way, this is an array of 0 size arrays) but trying to access `scoressec[i][1]` and `scoressec[i][2]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: Same error where? what did you change?

Comment: changed the score size to 1 and the column values are returning as 0's